# Pandas: extend dataframe so that columns start at the beginning of the calendar week (Monday)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

Suppose I have a dataframe with a columns index that contains dates. The first date is not a Monday. As a simple example:

```
# Imports
import numpy as np  # version 1.20.3
import pandas as pd  # version 1.3.4  

# Dataframe initialization
np.random.seed(0)
col_idx = pd.date_range(start="2022-12-22", end="2023-01-15", freq="D")
data = np.random.rand(5, len(col_idx))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_idx)
```

I would like to extend the dataframe such that the first date is on the closest Monday (2022-12-19 in this example). Basically I want to prepend a few extra columns to ensure that my dataframe starts with a full calendar week. All data values in the newly created columns can be set to 0.0.

What would be a smart way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with new datetimes created by [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with count previous `Monday` by subtract [`Timestamp.dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.dayofweek.html):

```
date = df.columns[0] - pd.Timedelta(df.columns.dayofweek[0], 'day')

#alternative
#date = df.columns[0].to_period('W').start_time
print (date)
2022-12-19 00:00:00

new = df.columns.union(pd.date_range(date, df.columns[0]))
out = df.reindex(new, axis=1, fill_value=0) 

#if consecutive datetimes
#out = df.reindex(pd.date_range(date, df.columns[-1]), axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print (out)
   2022-12-19  2022-12-20  2022-12-21  2022-12-22  2022-12-23  2022-12-24  \
0           0           0           0    0.548814    0.715189    0.602763   
1           0           0           0    0.639921    0.143353    0.944669   
2           0           0           0    0.570197    0.438602    0.988374   
3           0           0           0    0.039188    0.282807    0.120197   
4           0           0           0    0.677817    0.270008    0.735194   

   2022-12-25  2022-12-26  2022-12-27  2022-12-28  ...  2023-01-06  \
0    0.544883    0.423655    0.645894    0.437587  ...    0.087129   
1    0.521848    0.414662    0.264556    0.774234  ...    0.359508   
2    0.102045    0.208877    0.161310    0.653108  ...    0.368725   
3    0.296140    0.118728    0.317983    0.414263  ...    0.318569   
4    0.962189    0.248753    0.576157    0.592042  ...    0.396506   

   2023-01-07  2023-01-08  2023-01-09  2023-01-10  2023-01-11  2023-01-12  \
0    0.020218    0.832620    0.778157    0.870012    0.978618    0.799159   
1    0.437032    0.697631    0.060225    0.666767    0.670638    0.210383   
2    0.820993    0.097101    0.837945    0.096098    0.976459    0.468651   
3    0.667410    0.131798    0.716327    0.289406    0.183191    0.586513   
4    0.881103    0.581273    0.881735    0.692532    0.725254    0.501324   

   2023-01-13  2023-01-14  2023-01-15  
0    0.461479    0.780529    0.118274  
1    0.128926    0.315428    0.363711  
2    0.976761    0.604846    0.739264  
3    0.020108    0.828940    0.004695  
4    0.956084    0.643990    0.423855  

[5 rows x 28 columns]
```